# Constructing a promise problem equivalent to XSAT from subset sum

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

Consider $\Pi$ to be the problem to decide if there is a subset of numbers that sum to $0$ in the given list of integers.

How does one construct a promise problem equivalent to $xSAT$ from this? $xSAT$ is in $NP\cap coNP$.

How is it possible that the original problem was NP complete and the transformed problem is in coNP?

Doesn't this mean NO instances also have short certificates for the original problem $\Pi$?

Comment: By xSAT, do you mean Exact 1-in-3-SAT? If so, where do you get that $xSAT \in NP \cap coNP$?

Comment: On Promise Problems
in memory of Shimon Even (1935{2004)
Oded Goldreich

Comment: [PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.140.3268&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Goldreich's paper is about promise problems, so NP doesn't quite have its usual meaning. You'll have to give us more context if you want any more help, but I would suggest you first read Goldreich's paper yourself.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus this was in 2013 (need to recollect).